# i'm trying to post to a localhost API and i get --> java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out

Tags: android, angular, api, nativescript

I'm building an application with NativeScript, so my android phone is connected to the computer with USB cable for debugging.

but when I try to post from my phone after I run the app it keeps to give me this error:
`System.err: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out`

I tried all and so far I don't know what's the problem.

***when I try to post to the server from "Postman" it works fine.

thank you!

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { User } from "../viewModels/userViewModel/userViewModel";
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    private serverUrl= "http://192.168.14.155:61986/api/Users/PostUser";

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    register(user:User){
        console.log("you are joing to use "+user.email+" as your Email");


      const req = this.http.post(this.serverUrl, {
      username: user.email,
      email: user.email,
      password: user.password
    }).subscribe(
       res => {
          console.log(res);
        },
        err => {
          console.log("Error occured");
        }
      );
    }

}
```

those are the errors accured:

```
System.err: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:334)
System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)
System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
System.err:     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:586)
System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:113)
System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:1432)
System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:1390)
System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:1667)
System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:133)
System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:466)
System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:371)
System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:130)
System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:261)
System.err:     at org.nativescript.widgets.Async$Http$RequestOptions.writeContent(Async.java:313)
System.err:     at org.nativescript.widgets.Async$Http$HttpRequestTask.doInBackground(Async.java:536)
System.err:     at org.nativescript.widgets.Async$Http$1.run(Async.java:482)
System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
System.err:     at org.nativescript.widgets.Async$PriorityThreadFactory$1.run(Async.java:52)
System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
JS: Error occured
```

Comment: Is you phone and pc in same network?

Comment: no, but i tried also to connect them to the same network and it didnt worked, also i tried to open a hotspot from my phone and connect it from my computer..   both didnt helped.

Comment: `when I try to post to the server from "Postman" it works fine.`. Yes. Postman on your PC. But try postman on your phone. Or another PC in your lan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your mobile and PC are in different network, connect your device through USB and enter following command in Command prompt:

`adb reverse tcp:61986 tcp:61986`

Then instead of `http://192.168.14.155:61986/api/Users/PostUser` use 
`http://localhost:61986/api/Users/PostUser`

Comment: @jonny Great! remember to mark the answer as approved if it was useful, so that others can benefit too!

Comment: sure ! can you tell me what this commend exactly do ?

Comment: Reverse a socket connection. You can consider it as port forwarding. It's probably called "reverse" because it's setting up a "reverse proxy" in which a http server running on your phone accepts connections on a port and wires them to your computer Or vice versa

Comment: `enter following command in Command prompt:` Command prompt on PC?

Comment: Ok. But how can that install a proxy on the phone? And install a http server on the phone? That is beyond magic.

Comment: @greenapps it won't install server on phone, it will just rewire the connection

Comment: Well it was you who said so: `.. it's setting up a "reverse proxy" in which a http server running on your phone accepts ...`. So please dont confuse me. Pretty unclear what is happening.

Comment: @greenapps Oh yes, got it. I think in a bid to over simplify the description I added that description. Basically I wanted to indicate that the connection is rewired. I cannot edit my comment now but the discussion should be useful. Thanks for highlighting.

Comment: If you only say that it is rewired than i still understand nothing. And have to believe in magic ...

Comment: @greenapps what I mean by rewire is:it allows you to forward request from your device's port to your host/PC port. The first parameter is the port on the device and the second is the port on the host/PC you want to forward to.

Comment: But needing a USB cable to use an Android app to communicate with a server on a PC is not the solution of course. Wifi should do it. Of course it can. Here too.

Comment: @greenapps I had recommended him to use the wifi. But due to some connection issues he couldn't do so. Sometimes networks in your office doesn't allow you to do so.